# I cannot run a haddop jar on Hadoop 3.0.0-cdh6.3.2

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have a machine with Hadoop 3.0.0-cdh6.3.2 installed .
I ran this

```
hadoop jar helloworld.jar solution.CardDriver /user/vmuser/playing_cards_simple /user/vmuser/output
```

And show me this error:

```
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2023-01-22 16:24:13.729]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1674418413963_0005_02_000001
Exit code: 1

[2023-01-22 16:24:13.730]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/vmuser/appcache/application_1674418413963_0005/container_1674418413963_0005_02_000001/launch_container.sh: line 19: ${/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce}: bad substitution

[2023-01-22 16:24:13.731]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
/var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/vmuser/appcache/application_1674418413963_0005/container_1674418413963_0005_02_000001/launch_container.sh: line 19: ${/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce}: bad substitution

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1674418413963_0005 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
```

I set

```
/etc/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml 
/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml
```

with this value

```
HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce} . I tried with $HADOOP_HOME but gave a lot of errors.
```

I didn't change the yarn-site.xml (The values of yarn.application.classpath are set but I don't if there is right .
The values of yarn-site.xml are :

```
    <description>Classpath for typical applications.</description>
     <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
     <value>
        $HADOOP_CONF_DIR,
        $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*,$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*,$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*,$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*,
        $HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*,$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*
     </value>
  </property>
```

Pls your help I invested several days on this , any light can help me at lot .

Comment: `For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://localhost:8088/cluster/app/application_1674418413963_0005 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.` what does that say?

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue with the variables on /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <description>Classpath for typical applications.</description>
     <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
     <value>
       /etc/hadoop/conf,
       /usr/lib/hadoop/*,
       /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*,
       /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*,
       /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*,
       /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*,
       /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*,
       /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*,
       /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*
     </value>
  </property>
```

And you don't need anything else .